# Delete association in hasMany relation

Tags: grails, grails-orm, relationship

I'm new in Grails and have a problem with the hasMany relation. I've got the following classes:

```
class Twitter{
    String someVariable
    static hasMany = [subscribedUsers: User]
}

class User {
    String username
    String anotherVariable
}
```

In my Code beforde, I added a User to the relationship via

```
twitterInstance.addToSubscribedUsers(springSecurityService.currentUser)
```

which worked fine. But now, I am trying to delete a User from the relationship without deleting the User object. I've read some tutorials and the GORM doc, but couldn't find something like

```
twitterInstance.removeFromSubscribedUsers(springSecurityService.currentUser)
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/removeFrom.html

Comment: Also, look at the Cascading / Deleting children section (~1/4 of the way down) here: http://blog.springsource.org/2010/07/02/gorm-gotchas-part-2/

Comment: What you mean it doesn't work? Are you getting an error?

Comment: I don't get an error. But if i print the hasMany list, the items are still there.

Comment: Shouldn't you have belongsTO in the User Class ?

Comment: @user1738433 did you twitterInstance.save() at the very end?

Comment: I did not want to write belongsTo because I thought belongsTo means that a user just can have Twitter as instances but in my business logic a User can also have other instances (networks), thus belongsTo doesn't fit my business logic. and a .save did not help too.

Comment: The same scenario.. No exception, but items are still there.

Answer (score 1):

Cause: [JIRA](http://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-5804)

**Solution:**

*Change*

```
twitterInstance.removeFromSubscribedUsers(springSecurityService.currentUser)
```

*to:*

```
def user = twitterInstance.subscribedUsers.find{it.id == springSecurityService.currentUser.id}
twitterInstance.removeFromSubscribedUsers(user)
```